# Postfix SASLnot workign on upgrade to 19.10

Tags: postfix, sasl

I upgraded from 18.04LTS to 19.10. However, postfix with SASL (cyrus) has stopped working. It is configured as a smarthost/relay for smtp.office365.com:587 using the normal methods as described widely.

Without debug settings, there is an usual "invalid parameter" error in the log:

```
Nov 17 00:15:21 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[2277]: 939A25A20DB: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.office365.com[52.97.133.242]: invalid parameter supplied
Nov 17 00:15:21 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[2278]: AB6735A0D5A: to=<ianb@removed>, relay=smtp.office365.com[40.100.174.194]:587, delay=214662, delays=214661/0.02/0.46/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.office365.com[40.100.174.194]: invalid parameter supplied)
```

After some debugging, below is a section of mail.log at level 4.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.
Ian

```
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: Using ESMTP PIPELINING, TCP send buffer size is 87040, PIPELINING buffer size is 4096
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_password_maps: smtp.office365.com: not found
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: maps_find: smtp_sasl_password_maps: hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password(0,lock|fold_fix|utf8_request): [smtp.office365.com]:587 = (removed):(removed)
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: smtp_sasl_passwd_lookup: host `smtp.office365.com' user `(removed)' pass `(removed)'
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: starting new SASL client
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: name_mask: noanonymous
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: smtp_sasl_authenticate: smtp.office365.com[52.97.146.130]:587: SASL mechanisms LOGIN XOAUTH2
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/smtp[22488]: xsasl_cyrus_client_get_user: (removed)
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/qmgr[22373]: warning: private/smtp socket: malformed response
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/qmgr[22373]: warning: transport smtp failure -- see a previous warning/fatal/panic logfile record for the problem description
Nov 18 20:55:56 ianb-pc postfix/master[18888]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/smtp pid 22490 killed by signal 11
```

Comment: more logs needed (before and after)

Answer (score 3):

Solution! Description of issue and solution is here:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1575424

Quick read: add this line to main.cf:

```
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login
```